No traffic when Wireguard connection established
I'm trying to make the most basic Wireguard installation for my home VPN. I've registered VPS with static ip address  '195.133.93.77' located in Netherlands. I've setup Wireguard on the VPS. Then I install and run Wireguard client app on my Windows machine. I expect now that my public ip address on client machine will be '195.133.93.77'. I run command in terminal to chech my public ip, but external source for detecting ip cannot be resolved:
curl http://ipecho.net/plain
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ipecho.net

Actually, all other sources cannot be resolved after establishing Wireguard connection, e.g. when I try to ping youtube:
ping youtube.com
Ping request could not find host youtube.com. Please check the name and try again.

The same is happening when I ping youtube (and other resources) by ip address:
ping 172.217.16.206    
Pinging 172.217.16.206 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out. 

How I did setup Wireguard:
1)installed wireguard
2)setup ip forwarding in /etc/sysctl.conf
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

3)configured firewall
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw allow 51820/udp
sudo ufw enable

4)generated keys and made Wireguard server configuration in etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
[Interface]
PrivateKey = cBPCxDgoyd1977Hv17Un0PefHGZcRtMnjFmcPzmetWg=
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = JNkZqJSh1GndiLYOYjy0gCKz+aBag9leyqSg7bPQ1GQ=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32

5)made client configuration file
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.2/32
PrivateKey = GLmb7zi+vtM2yoAydmiTErW0u/0UvSHQhq/oRJHo6X4=
DNS = 1.1.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = 4rg4pc8GzIttqgT+OX09XPSQNV8QMzL6Y4COSszFLig=
Endpoint = 195.133.93.77:51820
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0

6)started client app on my Windows machine, imported client configuration file, established VPN connection
Please advise, why there is no traffic after VPN connection is established. Thanks.

Please list the steps you've taken to complete the install and configuration here in this question. Including a link and saying you did something LIKE that isn't sufficient and doesn't tell us what you've actually done. What is your network config? Do you have a static IP from your host? What role does "ipecho.net" play in your configuration?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It is important to note that WireGuard does not have a connection (in the TCP sense). It cannot explicitly detect failure of peer connectivity.

You really shouldn't post your private keys on the internet. It would be a good idea to change those on your vps server.

@kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze no worries, keys are inactive but they make question more readable rather than wildcards.
